# Why did i lose this hand with 2 pair?

Tags: hand

I had two pairs (44 and 66)...

[image: HandReplay]

Comment: Question should have all the information.  Don't just post a link to and image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You and the player who won the pot both have 2 pair - both Queens and Sixes. He has a `K` kicker and you only have a `J` kicker, so he wins.

Your best 5 card hand from the 7 available is not `6644x`, it's `QQ66J` (i.e. you're playing the board). Your opponent holding K♠5♥l has a best hand of `QQ66K`, which beats you on the kicker.

You've suffered what's known as being counterfeited on the river here (you had the best hand until the river came), unlucky.

If the turn had been an `A` instead of a `J`, you would have chopped the pot 3 ways as you would all have been playing the board then.

Comment: Thanks for accepting! If you found the answer useful, please feel free to also upvote. :)